# How to filter by date with python's datatable

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have the following datatable, which I would like to filter by dates greater than "2019-01-01". The problem is that the dates are strings.

```py
dt_dates = dt.Frame({"days_date": ['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03']})
```

This is my best attempt.

```py
dt_dates[f.days_date > datetime.strptime(f.days_date, "2019-01-01")]
```

this returns the error

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Expr

what is the best way to filter dates in python's datatable?

## Reference

[python datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html)

[f-expressions](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/f-expressions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datetime syntax is incorrect, for converting a string to a datetime.

What you're looking for is:

```
dt_dates[f.days_date > datetime.strptime(f.days_date, "%Y-%m-%d")]
```

Where the 2nd arguement for strptime is the date format.

However, lets take a step back, because this isn't the right way to do it.

First, we should convert all your dates in your Frame to a datetime. I'll be honest, I've never used a datatable, but the syntax looks extremely similar to panda's Dataframe.

In a dataframe, we can do the following:

```
df_date = df_date['days_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m'%d))
```

This goes through each row where the column is 'dates_date" and converts each string into a datetime.

From there, we can use a filter to get the relevant rows:

```
df_date = df_date[df_date['days_date'] > datetime.strptime("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")]
```

Answer (score 1):

[datatable version 1.0.0](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/v1.0.0.html#v1.0.0) introduced native support for date an time data types. Note the difference between these two ways to initialize data:

```
dt_dates = dt.Frame({"days_date": ['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03']})
dt_dates.stypes

> (stype.str32,)
```

and

```
dt_dates = dt.Frame({"days_date": ['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03']}, stype="date32")
dt_dates.stypes

> (stype.date32,)
```

The latter frame contains *days_date* column of type [*datatable.Type.date32*](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/type/date32.html) that represents a calendar date. Then one can filter by date as follows:

```
split_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
dt_split_date = dt.time.ymd(split_date.year, split_date.month, split_date.day)
dt_dates[dt.f.days_date > dt_split_date, :]
```